# При попытке установить Django, возникает такая проблема

Tags: python, django

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\Total Defense\Internet S
Security Suite\Anti-Phishing

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Comment: Ошибка возникает из-за недействительного пути к файлу сертификата TLS CA. Для решения проблемы нужно указать верный путь к файлу или установить правильный сертификат. Если вы используете pip в командной строке, можете попробовать добавить флаг `--cert` с путем к файлу сертификата.

Comment: может быть подскажете где он должен находиться, вообще не могу найти у себя такое

Comment: попробуй `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org Django==3.2.3 --no-verify-ssl`

Comment: ну и будет хорошо, если обновить pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Большое спасибо, но при попытке обновить pip выдает точно такую же ошибку((